# event.stopPropagation() is not working in jQuery event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events, event-propagation

In my jQuery mobile app, I have this code

```
$(context).on("click", ".search-person", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    PROFILE_MODULE.getProfile(id);
});

$(context).on("click", ".search-person .ui-checkbox .ui-btn", function(e) {
    //toggle checkbox
    $(this).click();
    //don't change page
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

`.search-person` is a table row and `.search-person .ui-checkbox .ui-btn` is a checkbox in a column in a row.

If I click that checkbox, I don't want the row click event to trigger. But in this code, it still does after the `e.stopPropagation()` runs, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`e.stopPropagation();` does actually stop the propagation of the event, however what it does not prevent is `$(context).on("click", ".search-person", function() {});` from calling its handler, they are distinct and different events.

You can fix this by adding an element type condition to the selector that matches the `tr`:

```
"tr.search-person"
```

Now the selector does not match the `checkboxes` with the `search-person` class.

Here is a complete example:

```js
var context = $('table');

$(context).on("click", "tr.search-person", function() {
  alert('row');
});

$(context).on("click", ".search-person.ui-checkbox.ui-btn", function(e) {
  alert('check box');
  // this.click(); will also work but why bother 
  // if all you are doing is clearing the checkbox
  $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).prop('checked'));
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
tr.search-person {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="search-person">
    <td>Click Here and the Check Box</td>
    <td>
      <input class="search-person ui-checkbox ui-btn" type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="search-person">
    <td>Click Here and the Check Box</td>
    <td>
      <input class="search-person ui-checkbox ui-btn" type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively you can check to see the element type that triggered the event:

```
$(context).on("click", ".search-person", function() {
    if ($(this).is('tr')) {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        PROFILE_MODULE.getProfile(id);
    }
});
```

Comment: @omega please see my answer for an explanation of what is happening and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fixed it when I used

`$(selector).click(function(){ ... })`

instead of

`$(context).on("click", selector, function(){ ... });`

Comment: It doesn't work. Also, the .click() is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

You might also need to return false from the handler.

Comment: I think code initial code worked, but when I did a .click() it caused a new event propagation to happen.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it with this hack:

```
$(context).on("click", ".search-person", function(e) {
    if (!e.hasOwnProperty('_clickedName')) {
        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        PROFILE_MODULE.getProfile(id);
    }
});

$(context).on("click", ".search-person .ui-checkbox .ui-btn", function(e) {
    e['_clickedName'] = true;
});
```